# PHP mysql table move to table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables which are daily_matches and archived_matches. I want to move daily_matches' rows to archived_matches. But archived_matches has one more column which is match_date. I also want to insert yesterday date to match_date when i am moving the daily_matches table.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO archived_matches 
(league, hour, code, team_home, team_away, result, rate_home, rate_draw_, rate_away) 
SELECT league, hour, code, team_home, team_away, result, rate_home, rate_draw_, rate_away FROM daily_matches";
```

Above codes does not insert the match_date. Also that code does not work. It does not move the table. How can i move table and insert match_date ?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: the table columns have to match

Comment: *"But archived_matches has one more column which is match_date."* - So where is that?

Comment: isn't it better to create a view table out of those two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want insert also match date you should add the related  cols in insert and select eg:

```
 $sql = 
 "INSERT INTO archived_matches 
      (league, hour, code, team_home, team_away, result, rate_home, 
              rate_draw_, rate_away, match_date) 
SELECT league, hour, code, team_home, team_away, result, rate_home,
               rate_draw_, rate_away, subdate(current_date, 1) 
FROM daily_matches";
```